# Show contents of localStorage into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have this basic function :

```
pid = 1;
$(function() {
    if (localStorage["key"+pid] != null) {
        var contentsOfDiv = localStorage.getItem("key"+pid);
        $("#Div").html(contentsOfdDiv);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the `pid` value will change eventually and I don't want to overwrite the contents of the `key`.

How can I proceed to stack every `Div` content that `localStorage` is saving for me ?

Comment: What is the purpose of pid? Probably there is a cleaner way without joining strings and looking for matching keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate on localStorage entries just like on any object properties :

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    console.log(key, localStorage[key]);
}
```

So your code could be :

```
$(function() {
    var lines = [];
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (/^key/.test(key)) { // does the key start with "key"
           lines.push(key.slice(3) + ' = ' + localStorage[key]);
        }
    }
    $("#Div").html(lines.join('<br>'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but how can I put this to work with my function ? I am very new to javascript

Comment: Factastic. This was really helpfull

Comment: Just a geeky detail... wouldn't it be slightly more effective to use  `key.substr(0,3) === 'key'` instead of `/^key/.test(key)` ?

Comment: @ikaros45 Yes, [it's slightly faster](http://jsperf.com/startswithso) but I don't think it's worth the change. And... I like regexes :)

Comment: In my case it's been 33% faster. Imagine how many nanoseconds you can save in this routine hehe.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well, you want to use pid to loop over the object.

Best way to do this and avoid for in chain prototypical problems is the following:

(I think for this case you are better with an array rather than with an object)

http://jsfiddle.net/hqkD9/

```
    var localStorage = ['aaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd'];   // don't forget to declare with var

    var html_string = '';
    $.each(localStorage, function(index, value) {
        html_string += value + '<br>';
    });

    $('#my_div').html(html_string);
```

Comment: You probably should [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage).

Comment: It seems I did not even get close! You never stop learning new things =)